# Custom made menu hotkey problem, blender doesn't find it unless I run it form the text editor

Tags: scripting, add-on, shortcut

I am new to scripting in blender, kinda new to python as well.
I followed a tutorial on how to make a custom menu in python, and then add it as an addon in blender. Now I installed it from file and it worked, I enabled it and assigned an hotkey, but unless I run it from the text editor I get this error:

Report: Error
Menu "gino" not found.
(gino is the bl_idname)

[image]

if I run the script from the text editor once, the hotkey start working and I don't receive any errors. 
How do I fix this so that when I start Blender my addon work with that hotkey?

This is the code:

```
bl_info = {"name" : "GinoMenu","category" : "3D View","author" : "Edo"}


import bpy

class customMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "G I N O"
    bl_idname = "gino"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        #pie = layout.menu_pie()

        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cone_add")
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_circle_add")

        return{'None'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(customMenu)
    #bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name = customMenu.bl_idname)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(customMenu)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Please see the [`bpy.types.Menu` docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html) re naming convention for menus.  Something like `bl_idname = "MESH_MT_gino"`  Would also call the class the same `class MESH_MT_gino(bpy.types.Menu):`

Comment: @batFINGER thank you for your comment, will do but that shouldn't be what is causing the error, correct? Be patient if it's a lame question, I don't know the subject very well, yet.

Comment: Could be what is causing the error.  Also recommend putting version into info dictionary.  Are there any messages printed in system console when blender is starting?

Comment: @batFINGER thank you for your time, I tried renaming as you suggested and uninstalling and reinstalling the addon but I still get the same error:
Report: Error
Menu: "MESH_MT_gino" not found

Comment: Ok, you mention the addon is enabled, can you add a screenshot of the keymap?   I have addons that register menus, eg "TEXT_MT_nvim_buffers".  I can see it is registered in the python console by auto completing to see that  `bpy.types.TEXT_MT_nvim_buffers` (my menu) is registered.  Can call it from the console or from a keymap with `bpy.ops.wm.call_menu("TEXT_MT_nvim_buffers")` as expected.  Just looked again and wouldn't return anything from a menu.  (which is same as `return None`)

Comment: @batFINGER sorry for the delay, I missed part of your previous message before, seems it was a matter of adding blender version into the dictionary to make it work, thanx a lot for your help!

Comment: Yep that explains it. Could you please put together an answer.  2.8 does some checking of version number when registering addons (to give the might not work warning if version < 2.8)  IIRC it writes some error or warning to console re no version number.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone facing the same problem in the future
 here is the solution, thanx again to  batFINGER for helping me find it. 
you need to **make sure that you put your blender version in the script's dictionary**,
 in my example:

bl_info = {
    "name" : "customMenu",
 
    "category" : "3D View", 
    "author" : "Edo", 
    **"blender" : (2,80,0)** 
}